# Entity Framework Custom Field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a SQL table which I access via entity framework containing two columns, one for cost price and one for sale price. My table is called inventory so I therefore have an entity called inventory containing two properties - costPrice and salePrice.

What I want is a third column which will be the calculation of the difference between the two fields. Additionally I want to allow sorting of either of the three columns from within my view. A few options I've investigated so far are as follows:

Adding a new column to the SQL table - I am not allowed to physically do this.

Extending the inventory class using a partial class and setting up the custom field when I get the data via EF - I cannot do this as this would mean I have to get all 500,000 records from the table, put them into a list and perform a sort of this list based on the custom field, this would be very slow.

Performing the calculation within the view - this would work for displaying the data but I wouldn't be able to sort.

Lastly, creating a SQL view to hold the three columns and then adding the SQL view to EF. This works fine and is the only way I've found a good solution.

I just feel there must be a more modern way of doing this within EF as opposed to using a SQL view? 
Any ideas or suggestions would help greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Add third property (column to your entity):

```
public Entity
{
    public int Prop1 {get;set;}
    public int Prop2 {get;set;}
    [NotMapped]
    public int Prop3 // New property
    {
        get
        {
            return Prop2 - Prop1; // or whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Then select from the context this way

```
db.Entities
    .Where(...)
    .Select(x => new { Blabla1 = x.Prop1, Blabla2 = x.Prop2, Blabla3 = (x.Prop2 - x.Prop1) }) // select what you need here + the difference. !ANONYMOUS TYPE!
    .OrderBy(x => x.Blabla3)
    .Select(x => new Entity { Prop1 = x.Blabla1, Prop2 = x.Blabla2 }) // !CONVERT TO THE TYPE YOU NEED!
    .ToList();
```

Note that you'll select anonymous type here. You can convert it to the type you need at the last line if it's required.